# Which graph/chart library should I use with react material?

Tags: charts, react

I'm pretty much newbie to react. I've implemented admin console in [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/), [redux](https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework) with [react-material](https://github.com/BerkeleyTrue/react-material).

Which is good library to implement graphs and charts with before-mentioned stack?

Comment: I have added links and tags, please verify whether it is what you meant or not.

Comment: Please let us know what types of graphs and charts you need.

Answer (score 2):

[ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/) is a great! It is a commercial license but free to use under the branded terms.

I have some codepen examples:
[image]
[1(demo link)](http://codepen.io/nardecky/pen/ALmZBz)
[image]
[2(demo link)](http://codepen.io/nardecky/pen/NREQPY)

Heres their stuff:
[image]
[zingchart/react](https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-React)
[codepen](http://codepen.io/zingchart/)

Comment: Please add screenshots and license information, thanks! Links are not enough.

Answer (score 2):

[Essential Chart for JavaScript/React](http://reactjq.syncfusion.com/#app/chart) is an option.

[image: Chart Syncfusion]

```
ReactDOM.render(
<EJ.Chart id="3dcolumn"
    title = {title}
    series={series}
    commonSeriesOptions={commonSeriesOptions}
    primaryYAxis={primaryYAxis}
    primaryXAxis={primaryXAxis}
    enable3D= {true}
    enableRotation= {true}
    depth= {100}
    wallSize= {2}
    tilt= {0}
    rotation= {34}
    perspectiveAngle= {90}
    sideBySideSeriesPlacement= {true}
    load= "loadTheme"
    isResponsive= {true}
    legend = {legend}
>

</EJ.Chart>,
      document.getElementById('chart-3dcolumn'));
```

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is SciChart's [JavaScript / React Chart Library](https://www.scichart.com/javascript-chart-features/).

[image: React Charts - SciChart.js]

They have recently released a [react wrapper](https://www.scichart.com/blog/react-charts-with-scichart-js/) and all the [JS Chart demos](https://demo.scichart.com/) are in React / Typescript.

SciChart is commercial software but has a [free community edition](https://www.scichart.com/community-licensing/) for non-profit, non-commercial and educational use.

***As a disclosure**, I work for scichart!*

Comment: As soon as you start repeating the answer, it sort of becomes spammy.